# How to find where the memory leak are?

Tags: delphi

I've enabled memory leaks reporting:

```
ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
```

When I close my program I have a memory leak report like this :

[image]

But how to find exactly which objects was not released ?

Comment: Search through code where these leaks are and resolve them.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for those close votes. Tracking down memory leaks in your application is a is a problem directly related to programming.

Comment: It is a problem related directly to programming when you are making some effort in finding those leaks, and show attempts you've made in order to fix them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use [LeakCheck](https://bitbucket.org/shadow_cs/delphi-leakcheck) (or FastMM Full Debug Mode). LeakCheck outputs stack trace of the allocation (if enabled). It may even output dependency graph of the leak so you get the root cause.

LeakCheck way:

- Download LeakCheck (you may use Delphinus)
- Enable MAP file generation in compiler options
- Add `LeakCheck, LeakCheck.Setup.Trace` to DPR `uses` section
- Optional: add `LeakCheck.Report.FileLog` to `uses` as well (use with care as it scans the memory) - it generates `.dot` file that you can pipe through Graphviz to generate the leak graph
- Run your app
- Analyze the output